# Automatic dollars signs in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

Every time I use a command like `\left(\right)` in TeXstudio, it automatically wraps it in dollars signs but I don't want it to happen. How can I stop the automatic dollar sign problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `TeXstudio` and choose `Preferences`. Under "Completion", untick "Auto Insert Math delimiters where needed".

[image]
[image]