# TexStudio: Auto insert Math Delimiters does not show up as an option

Tags: math-mode, auto-completion

My Problem is the following:
I would like to activate the option to set the $-signs automatically when i use autocomplete. The Problem is that the option is just not available. That is what i want:
[Automatic dollars signs in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471294/automatic-dollars-signs-in-texstudio?newreg=132302c827d848c6b130fbf9f6ace61c)

And this is how it looks for me:
[image]

The checkbox is just missing...

I have this issue with my Desktop PC, running Linux Mint 19.1
I have the checkbox available on my Laptop, running Windows.
On both I use TeXstudio 2.12.6

And before someone suggest it, turning on advanced options does not help.

I am not sure how i ended up in this situation and so far i could not find any solution, so i decided to ask for advice here..thanks in advance.